# Help with this question about rank of Hessians

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve this question below:

[image]

I need a hint to begin to solve this question.

Comment: The answer to the first question in your title is certainly YES if $f$ and $\varphi$ are well-defined functions (which can be said without reading the context).

Comment: @GDumphart so did the author make a mistake?

Comment: True, $\varphi (a)=b$, but Hessian does not depend on the function's value _in that point alone_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin could you explain a little bit more? thank you.

Comment: See, they require $\varphi$ to be a diffeomorphism for a reason. Otherwise you'd be able to construct a pathological example (say, a function without inverse) which would violate the statement, despite still having $\varphi(a)=b$.